# How to get the values of the textfields from one method to another method in the same class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

This is for Selenium Webdriver.

I have several methods inside the same class but I have these two methods that I need to connect(?)

1. The first one is to enter values in a form
2. The second one is to verify if the entered values are correctly displayed in the email template sent after submitting the form.

Here's my code:

```
public void enterRequiredAndOptionalDetails(){

        String randomFName = "Tester"+generateRandomAlpha(2);
        String randomLName = "Last"+generateRandomAlpha(2);
        String generatedEmail = randomFName+randomLName+"@test.com";
        String randomPhoneNum = "045"+generateRandomNumber(7);
        String randomTimeToCall = generateRandomNumber(1)+"am to " + generateRandomNumber(1) + "pm";
        String randomComment = "Hi, this is a sample comment"+generateRandomAlpha(5);

        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_FirstName,randomFName);
        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_LastName,randomLName);
        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_Email,generatedEmail);
        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_Telephone,randomPhoneNum);
        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_PreferredTimeToCall,randomTimeToCall);
        sendKeys(Properties_Details_NewLeadModal_Comment,randomComment);
```

```
public void verifyNewLeadDetailsInEmail(){
        // I don't know how to use the entered values from the enterRequiredAndOptionalDetails().
        // this is where I verify if the entered values from the enterRequiredAndOptionalDetails() matches the values sent in the email template.
    }
```

I have tried creating a separate method to just store the values entered in the form, but still, I don't know how to use it in verifyNewLeadDetailsInEmail() method.

Comment: don't generate those values in that method. Even better, don't dynamically generate values at all. Depending on what is generated, you might get an other result, making your test fail

Comment: Hi @Stultuske, thanks for your suggestion. That's a great point and that'll make it more easier! However, the reason why I generated random values is because I wanted to test if the system is correctly capturing the values entered by the different users. But if it's too complex to be coded, I'll make the values static then. Thanks, again:)

Comment: it's not really about "difficulty", it's about creating a possibility where you don't notice you don't test all the scenario's, and where you test certain scenario's you shouldn't be (re-)testing

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the details in an `ArrayList<String> arraylist` in enterRequiredAndOptionalDetails() method and pass this to the `verifyNewLeadDetailsInEmail(ArrayList<String> enteredDetails)` and then perform validation.